# emberjs - filter navigation, bind active class on selected filter

Tags: javascript, ember.js

in one of my templates, I use extracted distinct properties (genres) from a list of items (videos), and use these genres to build filter navigation.

each genre in my template calls an action on my controller with its value.

snipped controller:

```
var VideoListController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

  genreFilter: "",

  actions: {

    filterByGenre: function(genre) {
        this.set("genreFilter", genre);
    }
  },

  genres: function() {
    var genres = this.get('content').map(function(video) {
        return video.get("genre");;
    }).filter(function(genre, index, arr) {
        return arr.indexOf(genre) == index;
    });
    return genres;
  }.property("content"),

  filteredContent: function() {
    var content = this.get("arrangedContent");
    if (!Ember.isEmpty(this.get("genreFilter"))) {
        return content.filterBy("genre", this.get("genreFilter").valueOf());
    } else {
        return content;
    }
  }.property("arrangedContent.[]", "genreFilter"),

});
```

snipped template:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" {{action "filterByGenre"}}>ALL</a></li>
    {{#each genres}}
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#" {{action "filterByGenre" this}}>{{this}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

what I would like to do, is put the `active` class on the filter navigation item that corresponds with the controller's `genreFilter`. i.e.

if `genreFilter` = '', then `ALL` will have the `active` class.

if `genreFilter` = 'comedy', then `comedy` will have the `active` class.

this would essentially be identical to how ember is able to automatically assign `active` on your `{{linkto}}` navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I needed to filter in a lot of my templates, I decided to split the filter UI into a view. The view than uses jQuery selectors to apply the active style

parent template:

```
{{view "filters" contentBinding="filters" appliedFilterBinding="filterValue"}}
```

filters template:

```
<div class="">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="filter-item" data-id="all" {{action "filter" ""}}>ALL</a></li>
    {{#each view.content}}
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="filter-item" {{bind-attr data-id=this}} {{action "filter" this}}>{{this}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}

</ul>
```

filters view:

```
var FiltersView = Ember.View.extend({

templateName: 'filters',

_updateAppliedFilterUi: function() {
    this.updateAppliedFilterUi(this);
}.observes('appliedFilter'),

updateAppliedFilterUi: function(context) {
    context.$('.filter-item').removeClass('active');

    var appliedFilter = context.get("appliedFilter");
    if (Ember.isEmpty(appliedFilter)) {
        appliedFilter = "all";
    }
    var filterElementSelector = '.filter-item[data-id="' + appliedFilter + '"]';
    context.$(filterElementSelector).addClass('active');
},

didInsertElement: function() {
    var self = this;
    Ember.run.schedule('afterRender',function(){
        self.updateAppliedFilterUi(self);
    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You could use a computed property like this:

**Your template**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" {{action "filterByGenre"}}>ALL</a></li>
    {{#each genres}}
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li {{#if activeGenre}} class=activeGenre>{{/if}} ><a href="#" {{action "filterByGenre" this}}{{this}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

**Your computed property** (pseudo code)

```
activeGenre: function() {
        // do your logic here
        return content;
    }.property('genreFilter')
```